# terminal (or command line) -send command from node js

Tags: node.js

```
/home/akash/campaign/mcd-cmd.sh localhost 54322 "mcd campaign create" /home/akash/campaign/campaign.json
```

I have some command which u can see above .. I need send this request from node js code to terminal and get some data from response . I found this library for this purpose https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander , but I can't figure out how to configure it in right way.Maybe someone know better library for this purpose . I need some help .

Comment: Looks like you want to execute a shell script with some arguments. For that you could use `spawn()` from built-in `child_process` module

Comment: Can I use smth like this ? `let exec = require('child_process').exec; exec('/home/akash/campaign/mcd-cmd.sh localhost 54322 "mcd campaign create" /home/akash/campaign/campaign.json', (error, stdout, stderr) => {  })`

Comment: Well, I don't see any reason you can't use exec. There are similar examples to what you're trying to do in official docs.

Comment: I will check it and let you know is it working ) thanks for you help )